# how to setvalue in <md-input> angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I get data from db, and now would like to set data 
Here is a template.html:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="container-block">
    <form class="register" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form.value)" >

      <div class="info-block">
        <div class="image-block">
          <img src="../../assets/main/users.png" alt="">
          <div class="opacity"><a href="" class="photo-icon"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="person-info">
          <h2>John Smith</h2>
          <p>madcrocs@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" [ngClass]="{'indiv':!form.controls['username'].valid && form.controls['username'].touched}">
        <span>Username</span>
        <md-input  formControlName="username" class="demo-full-width">tyt</md-input></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the component code is:

```
 this.form  = this.fb.group({
      username: ['HELLO', Validators.required],
      tags: ['', notEmpty]
    });
```

Now I would like to see HELLO as a input value. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code: `[formGroup]="form"` vs `[formGroup]="formP"`.

Comment: I wrote it by mistake. But problem is still exist.

Comment: No errors or anything? Where is your second code snipped placed within your component?